# Two way communication in nestjs

Tags: angular, nestjs

I am stuck in a problem and I know you'll have a solution to it. I have a client and merchant interface. There can be n client and n merchants. Client can send a request to merchant. Merchant can accept it or reject. If the merchant doesn't accept it, it will be automatically rejected in 5 mins. How will I notify my client that you request has been accepted or rejected,while he's on the interface. Should I use socket or something else ? How do I implement this functionality ?

Comment: You may want to describe what have you tried so far, and also.

Comment: Yes, websockets (socket.io) will do the job